# converting a csv file to a TFRecord dataset

Tags: python, csv, tfrecord

I have a csv file that has only one column without any header. In each row, there is a string. Some rows are also empty.

```
This is string1
This is string2
This is string3
(empty row)
This is string4
(empty row)
This is string5
```

How can I convert this csv file to a TFRecord dataset so that I can later use it for machine learning purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'lab':['This is string1',
'This is string2',
'This is string3',
np.nan,
'This is string4',
np.nan,
'This is string5']})
```

I believe that you can use this to work.

```
   rec = df.to_records(index=False)
   print(repr(rec))

   s = rec.tobytes()
```

than you use the function:

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
"""Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

This function come from [TFRecord e tf.train.Example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord).

After this:

```
print(_bytes_feature(s))
```

The output:

> bytes_list {
> value: "0t\372\023t\177\000\000px\372\023t\177\000\0000y\372\023t\177\000\000\220\323*@u\177\000\000\260~\372\023t\177\000\000\220\323*@u\177\000\000\360{\372\023t\177\000\000"
> }

Then:

```
a=_bytes_feature(s)
a=a.SerializeToString()
```

In fact, we can serialize any string to a binary-string by operating the SerializeToString() method.
The output:

> b'\n:\n80t\xfa\x13t\x7f\x00\x00px\xfa\x13t\x7f\x00\x000y\xfa\x13t\x7f\x00\x00\x90\xd3*@u\x7f\x00\x00\xb0~\xfa\x13t\x7f\x00\x00\x90\xd3*@u\x7f\x00\x00\xf0{\xfa\x13t\x7f\x00\x00'
> 1

Comment: How can I save the dataset and later load it into another program?

Comment: I sure that you can using  `filename = 'test.tfrecord'
writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter(filename)
writer.write(serialized_features_dataset)`.  This example can be founded into the previous link.  Load the file is possible through  `filenames = [filename]
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
raw_dataset` also in previous link.